# Smaller subnet mask to "merge" VPN-connected LANs?

Tags: vpn, linux-networking, local-area-network, dhcp-server, virtual-network

I have two LANs connected to different internet connections (in different cities, in fact):

```
ISP1 -> LAN 1: 192.168.10.0/24
ISP2 -> LAN 2: 192.168.11.0/24
```

On each LAN is a router. Both routers talk to each other over a point-to-point OpenVPN link (`10.75.6.0/24`).

On each router runs a DHCP server:

```
Server 1: 192.168.10.1, 10.75.6.1
  --> DHCP: 192.168.10.50-192.168.10.100

Server 2: 192.168.10.2, 10.75.6.2
  --> DHCP: 192.168.11.50-192.168.11.100
```

I have set up routes on each server such that from any client on either LAN, you can `ping` any other client on either LAN, or access Samba file sharing etc., and it's all routed over the encrypted VPN link. Great.

**Now, the question**: would it be a good idea to change the subnet masks so the LANs look like this:

```
ISP1 -> LAN 1: 192.168.0.0/16
ISP2 -> LAN 2: 192.168.0.0/16
```

While keeping the DHCP settings the same? If I did this, would broadcast packets on LAN 1 get sent to LAN 2 (and vice versa)? Would I be able to force clients on each LAN to only receive DHCP addresses from their local server? Essentially I want people on either LAN to be able to access the other LAN as if it was "the same" LAN, but meanwhile be assigned an address based on which "sub-LAN" they are in.

*Note: IP addresses have been slightly changed for anonymity purposes.*

Comment: Why do you want to extend layer 2, what application requires you to?

Comment: Samba network browsing for example, or UPnP browsing.